# Help for non-engineer? Cantilevered load question

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis

[image]

Wondering if I may ask for some help from my engineering friends. I am a hobbyist woodworker and am trying to figure out a strategy for something I'm making. The idea is a drop leaf style table that attaches to the back of my table saw to add some additional workspace.

I have a large wood block secured to the saw top, as well as the extension table top which weighs about 40lbs (1.25" thick). I would like to use a 1" x 3/16" thick flat steel bar attached to the mounting block (2 x 5/16" lag screws) then 5/16" lag screws into the sides of the tabletop to act as the pivot for the top to flip up. I have included a rough drawing above.

My main question is whether the flat steel bar will deflect under the cantilevered load of the top. I have found calculators out there, but to be honest, wouldn't have an idea what to put in. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I really can't picture what direction is up, what the bar is doing, or how anything works here.  A 3/16 think steel plate as a cantilever will certainly deflect if there is any length over about 9 inches.  A 1 inch angle iron, on the other hand, would probably support your car out a couple of feet.   The weight of the extension isn't the issue, it's your weight as you lean on it and the weight of the work on it.  Your bolts are all significatnly stronger than the bar.

Comment: Thanks. The long vertical piece is the table top which will pivot and extend to be parallel with the block on the left. The table, in the extended position, will be supported by two legs. The steel bar only extends about 2 inches to the pivot point of the table top.

Comment: Maybe you could draw both the drop leaf up and down. It really isn’t clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: If the drop leaf, when extended, is supported by legs, why do you use the term “cantilever”?

Comment: Some color and or labels would be helpful in the drawing next time.

Comment: It sounds like the table surface will flip up and be supported with a leg? The pivot being the right most circle? I think 3/16 steel will be more than strong enough for this. If the steel plate is held flat it will be insanely strong. Twisting action is really all you'd have to worry about, and this arrangement doesn't give it the freedom to twist significantly.

Comment: I would increase the width of the steel strip to 1.25in if it's all the same however.

Comment: @EdDantes - How would you feel about adding legs to the end of the table that isn't supported?  That can be done in such a way that they fold out of the way when not in use but significantly increase how much weight your table can hold when it is in use.  Love the name by the way, do you also go by Abbey Busoni?